# How to (re-)render Login Component after App Component's async is finished?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to implement Firebase Login in App.js

Obviously, before the firebase async login is finished, Login Component will be called from React Router ( "/" path will call Login Component )

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Layout from './containers/Layout';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import firebase from './firebase/firebase';

import rootReducer from './store/reducers/index';
import * as action from './store/actions/index';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            isAsnycFinished: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const promise = firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            console.log(user);
            if (user) {        

                let loginDetails = {
                    isAnonymous: user.isAnonymous,
                    uid: user.uid,
                    isLoading: false,
                    isAsnycFinished: true
                };

                this.props.onUpdateLogin(loginDetails);

            } else {
                let loginDetails = {
                    isAnonymous: false,
                    uid: '',
                    isLoading: false,
                    isAsnycFinished: true
                };
                this.props.onUpdateLogin(loginDetails);
            }     

            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                isAsnycFinished: true
            });                

        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Layout /> //contains Login Component as a route
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {

    return {
        onUpdateLogin: (loginDetails) => dispatch(action.uploadLoginStatus(loginDetails))        
    }
}
```

Login Component:

```
class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            inputClassName: '',
            selectClassName: '',
            showLoading: true,
            showError: false,
            errorMessage: "",
            showLoginForm: false
        }

        console.log('props', this.props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    ....

   componentDidMount() {

        if(this.props.isLoading) { //from redux store
            this.setState({
                showLoading: this.props.isLoading,
                showLoginForm: false
            });
        }
        else {
            if(this.props.isAnonymous) {                                          
                this.props.history.replace('/profile');
                console.log('logged in');
            }
            else {
                this.setState({
                    showLoading: false,
                    showLoginForm: true
                });
            }
        }        
    }
```

So I want to show the loading icon on the login page.
When async function in app is finished, can the Login Component get new props?
If so, I can check the props and change the state in Login Component.

I tried componentWillReceiveProps() in Login Component. But I did not get the new props.

Do i need to call the async function in every component to make it work?

Reducer:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    isAnonymous: false,
    uid: '',    
    isLoading: true,
    isAsyncFinished: false
}

const Auth = (state = initialState, action) => {


    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.LOGIN_STATUS:
            return (
                {
                    isAnonymous: action.loginDetails.isAnonymous,
                    uid: action.loginDetails.uid,                    
                    isLoading: action.loginDetails.isLoading
                }
            );

        default: 
            return state;
    }

}

export default Auth;
```

Comment: You will need to provide more code... First thing add complete component code

Comment: What ia th relationship between App and Login?

Comment: App is Main Component which contain Layout Component. Layout Component is just routing the right component. In my case It is routing Login Component if the url is '/'

Comment: `<Layout {...this.state} />` - If i pass the state here, and i layout component `<Route exact path="/" component={Login} {...this.props} /> ` - Can get the `isLoading` props. But Is it possible in simpler way?

Comment: Sir, parent component is listening to the firebase auth. and if there is a change in auth, it updates, the reducer. Now if the child component is already mounted, the child component is not getting the new props from reducer. I tried componentwillreceiveprops. Do i need to render the parent component?